# How can I add dynamic urls in sitemap.xml in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an app which has `[Posts, Events, Groups etc]` which are created dynamically from server. In this case I want all the dynamic events url to be added inside the sitemap.

I am using the [@nuxtjs/sitemap](https://github.com/nuxt-community/sitemap-module) module.

```js
 modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',

  ],
  // site map configuration
  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://example.com',
    gzip: true,
    exclude: [
      '/secret',
      '/admin/**'
    ],
  },
```

Comment: You need to use the declared methods for the dynamic paths by either resolving a list of those potential dynamic values or statically declaring them. [See the documentation here](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/usage/sitemap-options#from-a-function-which-returns-a-promise)

Comment: Also, the crawler does not help here? It does not generate any stuff in `generate.routes`? @Ohgodwhy

Comment: So, did you achieved to do this?